# Create Directory + Sub Directories

Tags: c#

I've got a directory location, how can I create all the directories? e.g. C:\Match\Upload will create both Match and the sub-directory Upload if it doesn't exist.

Using C# 3.0

Thanks

Answer (score 85, accepted):

[Directory.CreateDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.createdirectory.aspx)(@"C:\Match\Upload") will sort this all out for you. You don't need to create all the subdirectories! The create directory method creates all directories and sub directories for you.

Comment: Reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.createdirectory.aspx

Answer (score 13):

```
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(@"C:\Match\Upload"))
{
  System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Match\Upload");
}
```

Comment: The directory may not exist at the if but still exist during the create attempt with that method. Don't bother with the exists and use a catch instead.

Comment: Actually calling CreateDirectory will not fail even if the directory exists, so using it is redundant.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example with a `DirectoryInfo` object that will create the directory and all subdirectories:

```
var path = @"C:\Foo\Bar";
new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(path).Create();
```

Calling `Create()` will not error if the path already exists.

If it is a file path you can do:

```
var path = @"C:\Foo\Bar\jazzhands.txt";
new System.IO.FileInfo(path).Directory.Create();
```

Answer (score 0):

for googlers: in pure win32/C++, use [SHCreateDirectoryEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762131(VS.85).aspx)

```
inline void EnsureDirExists(const std::wstring& fullDirPath)
{
    HWND hwnd = NULL;
    const SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES *psa = NULL;
    int retval = SHCreateDirectoryEx(hwnd, fullDirPath.c_str(), psa);
    if (retval == ERROR_SUCCESS || retval == ERROR_FILE_EXISTS || retval == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
        return; //success

    throw boost::str(boost::wformat(L"Error accessing directory path: %1%; win32 error code: %2%") 
        % fullDirPath
        % boost::lexical_cast<std::wstring>(retval));

    //TODO *djg* must do error handling here, this can fail for permissions and that sort of thing
}
```

Comment: Windows XP and 2003 only, says the documentation

Comment: Since when is boost pure win32