# Error checking folders & subfolders in first pst and create if not existing in second pst

Tags: vba, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I add a pst using `AddStore`. I then try to check if it has the same folders and subfolders as default pst. If not create the folders and then execute other commands.

I included a portion of the code where the looping and creating should be done.

I get

> "Cannot Create Folder"

in the line `newDestFolder = destFolderRoot.Folders.Add(sourceFolder.Name)`

**How do I check if folders do not exist in new pst and create accordingly? This should apply to subfolders as well.**

**($exception).StackTrace**

```
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Folders.Add(String Name, Object Type)
   at AutoBackup.ThisAddIn.SetSrcAndDst(String Src, String Dst) 
      in E:\projects\ThisAddIn.vb:line 76
```

**Code Portion**

```
sFolders = oNspace.Folders.Item(src_pst).Folders
destFolderRoot = oNameSpace.Folders.Item(dst_pst)
destFolders = oNameSpace.Folders.Item(dst_pst).Folders

For Each sourceFolder In sourceFolders
   For Each destFolder In destFolders
     If sourceFolder.Name = destFolder.Name Then
        'do something
     Else
        newDestFolder = destFolderRoot.Folders.Add(sourceFolder.Name)
     End If
  Next
Next
```

[image]

#Update

I tried another way using a `For Loop` to check it is working.

This time non-existing folder in the second pst is created, but there is another problem:
On the first loop it creates the non-existing folder in second pst but after the folder is created, the rest of the loops do not detect this condition `sFolders.Item(i).Name = dFolders.Item(i).Name` rather it returns the default folders like `Deleted Items, Inbox, Sent` to the `Else` Condition which is then returning error "Cannot Create Folder" as the folder is already in the second pst.

I am not getting any hints from googling.

```
For i = 1 To sFolders.Count
    If sFolders.Item(i).Name = dFolders.Item(i).Name Then
        Call CopyMail(sFolders.Item(i), dFolders.Item(i))
    ElseIf sFolders.Item(i).Name IsNot dFolders.Item(i).Name Then                
        dFolderN = dFolderR.Folders.Add(sFolders.Item(i).Name)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Directory + Sub Directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680836/create-directory-sub-directories)

Comment: Sorry. Its not probable solution.  My post is about outlook add-Inn written in VB.  thanks for checking up though

Comment: C# solutions will (almost) always work in VB.  Here's a link to the [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx).  It includes C# and VB examples.

Answer (score 0):

Appears your logic is attempting to create the sourcefolder, multiple times, after it exists.

I do not know what language you are using so here is a quick and dirty VBA way to bypass the error.

```
For Each sourceFolder In sourceFolders

    For Each destFolder In destFolders

        If sourceFolder.Name = destFolder.Name Then
            'do something

        Else
            ' attempt to create all other folders than destfolder
            '  without checking if sourceFolder exists

            ' for a specific purpose
            ' - when folder already exists bypass the error line 
            on error resume next
            newDestFolder = destFolderRoot.Folders.Add(sourceFolder.Name)
             ' turn bypass off
             '  return to normal error handling
             on error goto 0
        End If

    Next

Next
```

For efficiency you will probably want to move the Add logic so it runs after looping through all existing folders and you have determined sourceFolder does not exist in the second pst.