# c# directory not created exception occurred

Tags: c#, .net

How to create directory work internally in c#.

I am creating directory like

```
"C:\ProgramData\Temp\Temp1\Temp2\Temp3".
This "Temp\Temp1\Temp2\Temp3"
```

is not present. currently.

After I call method create directory in C#.

how to create directory? is it create one by one internally?
like "Temp" -> "Temp1" and so on?

If it is "Temp/Temp1/Temp2" is created and another program delete Temp1 directory before creating Temp2 so the exception is thrown? like directory not found?

Comment: Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680836/create-directory-sub-directories/1680841

Comment: Is it create one by one? internally?

Comment: In .NET Framework 4.8, it creates the directories one at a time, as you can see in the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/directory.cs,214).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create multiple directories from a single full path in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134392/how-to-create-multiple-directories-from-a-single-full-path-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

[Directory.CreateDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.createdirectory?view=net-5.0) does that already:

> Creates all the directories in a specified path.

For your question

> If it is "Temp/Temp1/Temp2" is created and another program delete Temp1 directory before creating Temp2 so the exception is thrown?

I think it's quite unlikely. Why should another program delete a directory that doesn't even exist yet?

The method may throw many exception, one of them probably in this unlucky case. You can try to implement that: create a thread that permanently deletes the directory in an endless loop, then create another thread which creates the directory.

> is it create one by one internally?

Even if it might be possible to answer this question, you should neither care nor rely on that implementation. Microsoft could change it with any update of the .NET framework. It could also depend on the file system. Perhaps they use TxF (file system transactions) if the file system supports it, like NTFS, but they can't for FAT32.

On Windows, they simply call the [CreateDirectory Windows API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createdirectorya) ([line 329](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/directory.cs,329) in the source code) but they could also switch to [CreateDirectoryTransacted Window API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createdirectorytransacteda)

Comment: Is it create one by one? internally? C# code?

Comment: @ArchitSoni: why do you care? MS could change it with any update of the .NET framework. It could also depend on the file system. Perhaps they use TxF if the file system supports it (like NTFS), but they can't for FAT32

Comment: Okay thanks. But internally check before it is already created or not? like "Temp1" or "Temp2"?

Answer (score 0):

As said Thomas Weller , Directory.CreateDirectory in C# makes the job.
For you question :

> If it is "Temp/Temp1/Temp2" is created and another program delete Temp1 directory before creating Temp2 so the exception is thrown?

I dont't understand the point and why would another app delete your directory.
If it is the case, this will an exception in the other app and the app which created the directory will have an exception when trying to acces this directory.